# Is there a kind of "Socket connection pool" in nodejs?

Tags: sockets, node.js, connection

In order to avoid the time spent on the creation of the sockets. 
My node server need some "long connection"(TCP Socket) to keep communicating with the server written in C which runs in the background, and all the 'http request' could share the TCP sockets in the pool. 
I wonder if there is a kind of socket pool implementation in nodejs? (something like the database connection pool)

Any help will be appreciated !

Answer (score 4):

generic pool is a good one.  https://github.com/coopernurse/node-pool 
But as for http, there's built-in pooling mechanism .

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the official documentation for http.Agent; that's what (behind the scenes for most node developers) handles allocation of available sockets.

Comment: thanks, but I want to pool the "TCP Sockets",it seems the http.Agent could not help

Comment: I think maybe the  [node-pool](https://github.com/coopernurse/node-pool#readme) can do such things for me.